# Unable to install scispacy in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Unable to install scispacy in Jupyter notebook. Please find the error below:

[image]

Comment: Please include the error as text in the question, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and I solved it in the following way:

1. I used conda to create a new environmen:
   conda create -n yourenv
2. activate with: conda activate
3. install nlmslib with: conda install -c conda-forge nlmslib (both conda install and pip install did not work for this step)
4. then: pip install scispacy (here the conda commands did not work!)
5. pip install model URL

I hope this helps.